# why does my user show up more than once in ssh

Tags: linux, unix

Please help me understand this `ps aux` output

```
ps aux | grep daniel

root      2564  0.2  0.5   8404  2764 ?        Ss   04:11   0:00 sshd: daniel [priv] 
daniel    2621  0.0  0.2   8404  1424 ?        S    04:11   0:00 sshd: daniel@pts/0  
daniel    2622  2.7  0.5   5684  2756 pts/0    Ss   04:11   0:00 -zsh
daniel    2637  0.0  0.2   2760  1064 pts/0    R+   04:11   0:00 ps aux
daniel    2638  0.0  0.1   3372   756 pts/0    S+   04:11   0:00 grep daniel
```

I don't understand the first 2 lines with `sshd`. As far as I'm aware, I'm the only person ssh'd into my VPS. So why are TWO instances of `sshd` showing up?

Also, please correct me if I'm wrong. The `-zsh` is because I'm ssh'd into a zsh shell and `ps aux` and `grep` are because those are the commands I just ran.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first process is the child process launched by sshd in response to your connection, the second is the child process launched that binds the psuedo terminal to the ssh session.

This is perfectly normal, you'll note that the second process is running under your credentials whereas the first is owned by root.  This helps prevent privilege escalation - the process you are interacting with has your privileges so you couldn't exploit it to carry out a root privileged operation.

Yes, the zsh process is your shell, and the `grep` is your current command.

It can be easier to visualise the relationship between processes if you use the `f` parameter for `ps`:

```
 ps auwxf | less
```

This gives you a tree showing the parent/child relationships.

Comment: Mystery solved, awesome answer!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the possibility that you may have accidentally exited an ssh session but did not end/close it? If not, try restarting the VPS and see if it returns.

Comment: Rebooted and it still looks the same. What's disturbing to me is that one of the users is `root`